# Portfolios in Tidyquant with changing weights over time and assets

Tags: r, portfolio

I'm trying to create a momentum portfolio with multiple assets, with daily data. This portfolio goes short in the lowest 33% of the assets and long in the highest 33% of the assets, based on the twelve-month previous return. Since the 12-month returns change over time, and with that the rank of the assets I want to reweight them on a daily basis.

I have a dataframe with all the stocks in one column, and want to use tidyquant since adjusting it to a timeseries, and with that a column for each asset individually, is very difficult due to the high number of unique assets (2386).

An example of my dataframe:

| ID | date | Return | weights |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-03 | 0.0065 | 0.0033 |
| 1 | 2019-01-04 | 0.0095 | 0.0034 |
| 1 | 2019-01-05 | -0.0065 | -0.0037 |
| 2 | 2019-01-03 | 0.0090 | -0.0033 |
| 2 | 2019-01-04 | 0.0019 | -0.0034 |
| 2 | 2019-01-05 | -0.0048 | 0.0037 |

If I run:

```
portret <- dfport %>%
    tq_portfolio(assets_col = id,
    returns_col = Return,
    weights = weights,    
    co_rename = "ret")
```

it gives me:

```
The number of weights does not match the number of unique assets.

2: Can't recycle `..1` (size 2386) to match `..2` (size 9059805).
```

I understand the reasoning behind this, but I am not interested in weights that are static i am interested in weights that alter daily in my portfolio.

Is there a way to make assign weight to the assets on a daily basis with tidyquant or another package?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately tidyquant does not have this feature. Best to use xts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).